# Retropie that works fine on a computer monitor but shows no signal in a car

Tags: display, retropie, debug

For the same Retropie (4.7.1) on a Pi 3B+ and the same HDMI cable, the Pi works fine on a computer monitor but shows no signal on the display of a car's rear entertainment system.

This is an Acura MDX 2016. The Pi was plugged into the car's AC power outlet that is for 115V appliances that are rated 150 W or less. The car's display works just fine when the signal is from the car's DVD system, or from a Google Chromecast plugged into the rear HDMI port.

How do I begin to understand the source of this issue and resolve it?

I tried:

1. Power supply: the Pi's Canakit power adapter, and the micro USB cable (of the Google Chromecast)
2. HDMI cable: the Pi's Canakit HDMI cable, and the monitor's HDMI cable
3. Testing the Pi before and after trying in the car. It works fine with the monitor.
4. Testing the car's display with the Chromecast immediately trying the Pi. The car's display works fine with the Chromecast

Comment: Try setting the car display resolution up first using `sudo raspi-config` on a clean install of Buster Lite.  Can you even tell if the Pi boots?

Comment: What resolution is the car display?

Comment: @CoderMike I think it's 2x WVGA side-by-side, 1600 x 480. Acura documentation isn't the best.

Comment: @Andyroo I will attempt what you say. On your question, I don’t know if it even boots. The Canakit on/off LED lit up suggesting it got power, but I could not see anything on the screen so I could not tell whether it booted.